Java print formatting
I need the grid to be aligned in columns the grid stuff includes 1 and 2 number strings but idk how to use print formatting
this is what i have but i want the numbers to be aligned by the right number
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "    " + grid[0][0] + "    " + grid[0][1] + "    " + grid[0][2] + "    " + grid[0][3] + "    " + grid[0][4] + 
        "\n     " + grid[1][0] + "    " + grid[1][1] + "    " + grid[1][2] + "    " + grid[1][3] + "    " + grid[1][4] + 
        "\n     " + grid[2][0] + "    " + grid[2][1] + "    " + grid[2][2] + "    " + grid[2][3] + "    " + grid[2][4] + 
        "\n     " + grid[3][0] + "    " + grid[3][1] + "    " + grid[3][2] + "    " + grid[3][3] + "    " + grid[3][4] + 
        "\n     " + grid[4][0] + "    " + grid[4][1] + "    " + grid[4][2] + "    " + grid[4][3] + "    " + grid[4][4];
    }

I expected
 1   12    14    23    1
12    1    12    53   26

and so on

Use printf method.

Looking at your expected output within your post, the columns of your table are left-justified (where the table hugs the left edge of the window) but the numerics are right-justified if they don't meet maximum digits for the largest elemental 2D array value.
Below is an example of how this could be done based on the code provided by @001. Table cell widths are automatically determined by the largest number of digits in any element contained within the 2D array. The s conversion character is used for this since the numerical value we'll be applying to each cell will ultimately be a String.
Right-justification for numerical values within each table cell is automatically carried out by again using String#format() and applying the maxDigits value in conjunction with the d conversion character within the format.
Read comments in code:
int[][] grid = {{1, 12, 14, 23, 1}, {12, 24, 12, 53, 26},
                {18, 44, 63, 5, 72}, {53, 4, 0, 83, 99}};
    
/* Get the greatest number of digits from any value contained within 
   any element in the 2D array. We are using streams for this instead 
   of `for` loops. This variable will be used for setting the table 
   cells width and right-justifying of numbers for Left-Justified table 
   cells where we want the numerics to appear right-justified:     */
int maxDigits = Arrays.stream(grid).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
                      .mapToObj(Integer::toString).mapToInt(String::length)
                      .max().orElse(0);

// Build the table:    
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int totalRows = grid.length;
for (int row = 0; row < totalRows; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
        /* Set cell columns widths and right-justify digits within. 
           each cell that do not meet maxDigits. All numbers within 
           each cell will be Left-Justified. If you want each cell 
           to be Right-Justified then remove the `-`.           */
        sb.append(String.format("%-" + (maxDigits + 3) + "s" + 
                        (col == (grid[row].length-1) ? "%n" : ""), 
                        String.format("%" + maxDigits + "d", grid[row][col])));
    }
}

// Display the Table:
System.out.println(sb.toString());

Output in console window:
 1   12   14   23    1   
12   24   12   53   26   
18   44   63    5   72   
53    4    0   83   99   


See: Formatter class.
public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
        if (row > 0) sb.append("\n");
        for (int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%5d", grid[row][col]));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

